# Can Windows Remote Desktop Connection connect to a Mac mini M1?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop

Can I use Windows Remote Desktop Connection to access a Mac mini m1 where both are running under my local network? Remote Desktop Connection work well from Windows to Windows. Is it possible to use it instead of adding some extra tools which can be less optimized?

I planned to buy a Mac mini and plug it to my internet box. So, I would access my Mac mini from Windows.

Remote Desktop Connection:

[image: Remote Desktop Connection]

Comment: What exactly is "Mstc"? You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: MTSC is Windows Remote Desktop application (C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe).  @OP: I think if you connect to the IP address of the MAC, it should work.

Comment: Are you trying to remote INTO the Mac using Remote Desktop, or remoting into the Windows computer from the Mac?

Comment: My question already answer that. I would access a mac from my windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Remote Desktop can be used *to access a Windows PC* & that is all. You can connect PC to PC or Mac to PC but not PC to Mac.

Mac uses the more common cross-platform VNC standard, so you need to be looking for a Windows app that supports VNC. Just search "VNC Windows".

Comment: Okay thanks you :)

Comment: Hi, it's late i know. I tested VNC and discover his bad perfomance (i tested in local network with one windows & mac mini both with ethernet). I use today Google chrome remote which is more powerful / complete and it's free.

Comment: It's free if you trust a company whose entire business plan & income is generated by advertising & user tracking. "There ain't no such thing as a free lunch." - google it;) btw, VNC is a protocol, not an application. There are a myriad VNC implementations for all platforms.